# Information security point of view when registering a domain and chosing a TLD

Tags: privacy, dns, dns-domain, domain

How much does the choice of the domain registrar and the TLD impact the security of my information?

I've learned that some registrars will require more personal information than others. I even had a case where a registrar demanded a copy of my ID and used the credit card.

Generally, the less information a registrar has the less information can be disclosed. What registrar is preferred considering that?

How much impact does the TLD have? Do some ccTLD benefit the privacy of the data. Are generic TLDs privacy friendlier, as they do not oblige a countries laws?

Just for clarification, I'm not talking about WHOIS Privacy, nor do I want to discuss the security of various payment methods.

Comment: Are you concerned about the service you're going to make available under that domain being linked to your personality? If so, registering a clearnet domain for yourself is going to be a bad idea, no matter at what registrar. And if that is not the case, I'd probably be more concerned about the registrar's reliability. For example, it could do very bad things to you and your users by resolving your domain to malicious servers some of the time. The fact that you own the domain will be more or less public anyway. (In many countries, this is legally required.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You're absolutely right, I just want to find a way to disclose as little information when registering as possible and the information that is required should be protected and not given out to anyone. I assumed that there are differences between registrars and the various TLDs (as they might oblige different laws).

Answer (score 1):

I had answered TLD registration privacy here (along with WHOIS): [How much can I trust domain registrars to honor Whois identity protection services?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137989/how-much-can-i-trust-domain-registrars-to-honor-whois-identity-protection-servic/147968#147968)

With payment, it isn't unheard of to request a form of government issued ID. This is quite common in countries that don't have "Chip and Pin" technology.

Registrars are required to post contact information for domain owners. Each will outline how much they collect, and what they do with it. Godaddy has their legal agreement here: https://ca.godaddy.com/Agreements/ShowDoc.aspx?pageid=REG_SA